# Web crawler links/page logic in PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, logic, web-crawler

I'm writing a basic crawler that simply caches pages with PHP.

All it does is use `get_file_contents` to get contents of a webpage and regex to get all the links out `<a href="URL">DESCRIPTION</a>` - at the moment it returns:

```
Array {
[url] => URL
[desc] => DESCRIPTION
}
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out the logic behind determining whether the page link is local or sussing out whether it may be in a completely different local directory.

It could be any number of combinations: i.e. `href="../folder/folder2/blah/page.html"` or `href="google.com"` or `href="page.html"` - the possibilities are endless.

What would be the correct algorithm to approach this? I don't want to lose any data that could be important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, regex and HTML don't mix. Use:

```
foreach(DOMDocument::loadHTML($source)->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a)
{
  $a->getAttribute('href');
}
```

Links that may go outside your site start with protocol or `//`, i.e.

```
http://example.com
//example.com/
```

`href="google.com"` is link to a local file.

But if you want to create static copy of a site, why not just use `wget`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first consider the properties of local links.

These will either be:

- *relative* with no *scheme* and no *host*, or
- *absolute* with a scheme of 'http' or 'https' and a *host* that
  matches the machine from which the
  script is running

That's all the logic you'd need to identify if a link is local.

Use the **[parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)** function to separate out the different components of a URL to identify the *scheme* and *host*.

Comment: be careful with parse_url it fails really easily :P

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look for http:// in the href. Else, you could determine if it starts with ./ or any combination of "./". If you don't find a "/" then you would have to assume that its a file. Would you like a script for this?

Comment: sure that would be a great help! :)