# how to get all the page links within a specific site?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I want to  program in php to get  all the page links within my site as i want to check the pagerank for each page of my site, is there a tool or a library or an implemented algorithm in php to get all the page links of a specific site?

Comment: It's sounds like you're describing a Google scraper.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919760/recognizing-http-links-and-creating-anchor-tags/5919821#5919821

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361285/web-crawler-links-page-logic-in-php might be useful for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
<?php
  $original_file = file_get_contents("http://www.your_domain.com/page");
  $stripped_file = strip_tags($original_file, "<a>");
  preg_match_all("/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is", $stripped_file, $matches);
?>
```

$matches[0] will contain the complete A tags; ex: `<a href="link">text</a>`

$matches[1] will contain only the HREFs in the A tags; ex: `link`

I hope this will help you.
Regards!